# Where do I find the code for the south west door in Zone 2 residental area?

Tags: off

Where do I find the code for the door shown below?

I know the code is

> 1402

But only because of reading some walkthroughs. I never actually figured out, how to figure this code out.
[image: The door at south west of the residental area of Zone 2]
Screenshot from a [playthrough by Sir TapTap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBAA2nPBd-8), hence the tracker at the bottom.